# Optaplanner - Multiple planning entities with same blockId- How to "move all" or "chain" or "shadow" to the same planning variable?

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to assign Timeslots to planningEntities
(containing room, groups, persons handled by constraint streams).

Some of these planning entities has a blockId.
When entity has a blockId the goal is to share timeslot with other entities with the same blockId.

I defined a constraint for this, but I can see that the solver does extremely many unnecessary moves.

```
public Constraint groupBlockConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
    return constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Lesson.class,
            Joiners.equal(Lesson::getSequenceGroup),
            Joiners.filtering((a, b) ->
                    !Lesson.withoutBlock(a, b)
                            && !Lesson.sameTimeslot(a,b)))
            .penalize("BlockSequence not in same timeslot", HardSoftScore.ofHard(15));
}
```

Is there a way to handle this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Constraints do not determine which moves the solver will be trying. Constraints are only used to score solutions which are achieved once moves are already performed.

Therefore if you're seeing moves which in your opinion should not be performed, you need to [configure your selectors](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#moveAndNeighborhoodSelectionIntroduction). Using [tabu search](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/local-search/local-search.html#tabuSearch) could, perhaps, also help here.

That said, without a more detailed question I can not provide a less generic answer.